# How to create the popup screen without adding any code inside the body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a popup window without adding any code inside the bode.
I have created it by having style and Javascript. BUt i have added the div inside the body.So how can i do it without adding the div inside the body of the code.

Note : No code must be added inside the body .

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.price').mouseover(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $parent = $this.parent(); // just to prevent so much jquery object creation
        var decide;
        if ($this.hasClass('price')) {
            decide = 'price';
        } else if ($this.hasClass('title')) {
            decide = 'title';
        }
        console.log(decide);

        if (decide == 'price') 
        {
          
           var result=  $parent.find('.price').text();
           var result_t=   $parent.find('.title').text();
        }     
$('#text').html('<form action="" method="">'+
'<div class="plugincss"><h2>Get an Instant Quote Texted to You!</h2></div>'+

'<div class="des"><div style="font-size:16px;padding-left:9px" id="errormsg"></div> '+
'<ul>'+
'<li>Select if you’d like a quote for a new or used vehicle</li>'+
'<li>Select the vehicle you’d like a quote for</li>'+
'<li>Enter your mobile number and a Quote will be texted to you instantly!</li>'+
'</ul>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="car_detail"><p>Car Model Name : ' + result_t+'</p>'+
'<p>Price  : ' + result+'</p></div><br>'+

'<div class="car_detail">'+
'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" width="100%">'+
'<tbody>'+
'<tr>'+
'<td>'+
'<input placeholder="First Name"  type="text" id="firstname">'+
'</td>'+
'<td>'+
'<input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" id="lastname">'+
'</td>'+
'</tr>'+
'</tbody>'+
'</table>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="car_detail"><p>Enter your mobile number</p>'+
'<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%">'+
'<tbody>'+
'<tr>'+
'<td width="25%"><input id="number1" style="width:82%" type="text"></td>'+
'<td width="25%"><input id="number2" style="width:92%" type="text"></td>'+
'<td width="25%"><input id="number3" type="text"></td>'+
'<td width="25%"><input type="button" class="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="reqquote" ></td>'+
'</tr>'+
'</tbody>'+
'</table>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="fut"><a href="#">SMS &amp; Data Rates Apply</a> | <a href="#">Privacy</a> | <a href="#">Terms of Use</a></div>'+
'</form>');

           $('#reqquote').click(function() 
   { 
    var Firstname = $("#firstname").val();
                var Lastname = $("#lastname").val();
   
   if (Firstname.length == 0 || Lastname.length == 0) 
     {
        
            $("#errormsg").css("color", "red");
            $("#errormsg").html('Your first and last name must be filled in.');
            return;
     } 
     
      var txtNumber1 = $("#number1").val();
            var txtNumber2 = $("#number2").val();
            var txtNumber3 = $("#number3").val();

     
     if (txtNumber1.length != 3 || txtNumber2.length != 3 || txtNumber3.length != 4) {
            $("#errormsg").css("color", "red");
            $("#errormsg").html('Your full ten digit mobile number must be entered.');
            return;
        }
  
  $("#errormsg").css("color", "red");
  $("#errormsg").html('sending requests...');
        smsnumber = txtNumber1 + txtNumber2 + txtNumber3;
   
    
   var varUrl = "https://services.prospectingdesk.com/pdeskwebapi/pdesklead/LeadMessage/newLead";
   
      var dealerid="1";
   var productid="1";
   var linkid="1";
   var newusedvehicle="N";
   var modelyear="2015";
   var make="Maruthi";
   var model="800";
   var trim1="SS";
   var ip="123.123.123.1";
   
   
   
   
var ExtUrl = varUrl + '?dealerid=' + escape(dealerid) + '&productid=' + escape(productid) + '&linkid=' + escape(linkid) + '&smsnumber=' + escape(smsnumber) + '&newusedvehicle=' + escape(newusedvehicle) + '&modelyear=' + escape(modelyear) + '&make=' + escape(make) + '&model=' + escape(model) + '&trim=' + escape(trim1) + '&Firstname=' + escape(Firstname) + '&Lastname=' + escape(Lastname) + '&ip=' + escape(ip);

           
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET", url: ExtUrl, dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (msg) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(msg);
        alert(data);
     alert('success');
                   
            },
  
            error: function (msg) {
                alert('fail');
            }
            });
   
      
            });
  


            
​            $('#modal').show();
            return false;
            });

            
         
   
   
   $(document).click(function(event) 
   { 
            if(!$(event.target).closest('#modal').length) 
   {
      $('#modal').hide();
   } 
   });
  
  
})
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
   .overlay-bg {
bottom: 35%;
right: 0px;
width: 600px;
height: 500px;
border-radius: 0px;
background-image: none;
cursor: auto;
position: fixed;
z-index: 10000;
transform: translateX(-424.5px) translateY(127.867px);
background-color: #FFF;
display:none;
        }

        .overlay-content {
width: 600px;
height: 500px;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: #FFF;
padding: 20px 50px;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
.fancybox-margin{margin-right:17px;}
```

```html
<div id="modal" class="overlay-bg"><div id="text" class="overlay-content"></div></div>
```

Comment: U must add it to the html code. Just after u want to hide it do  $(element).remove()

Comment: Do you mean you cannot change the original source HTML, or do you mean you cannot dynamically inject HTML at runtime?

Comment: Hi Actually i am telling is i need to create popup only using the javascript No code must added in the body of that code

Comment: oh like that.. joy..

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding the `div` and calling it with `$("#modal")` create it in the code

```
var modal = $('<div id="modal" class="overlay-bg"><div id="text" class="overlay-content"></div></div>')
```

Comment: You will still need to add that to something in the body

Comment: 1. That's a dynamic change, no edit to the body code is required 2. You can add it outside of the `<body>` if you do wish.  2.

Comment: Hi i have tried as you told but no response is coming.